# inner join mysql php

Tags: php, sql, session, pdo

How can I select the username, avatar etc based on users ID from users table without Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException please?

**PHP :**

```
$req_pm_list = $sql_connection->prepare('SELECT pm.receiver, pm.date_sent, pm.unread, users.username, users.avatar, users.session_id
    FROM pm
    INNER JOIN users AS user_receiver ON pm.receiver = users.id
    INNER JOIN users AS user_sender ON pm.sender = users.id
    WHERE sender = :id OR receiver = :id 
    GROUP BY users.id 
    ORDER BY date_sent ASC');
$req_pm_list->bindValue(':id', $_SESSION['id']);
$req_pm_list->execute();
$pm_list = $req_pm_list->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: which RDBMS are you using, mysql or mssql? Two different animals here.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using the aliases `n` and `o` instead of `users` on your select list,  join conditions and the group by?

Comment: Please provide us with the error you receive. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php Additionally is emulation on? You can't use the same placeholder name without it.

Comment: Is it users , or is it n. You decide

Comment: I removed both `mysql` and `sql-server` tags. You will need to use "one" of those and not both. As I said earlier, those two are different. That to me, made the question unclear.

Comment: I just want get the sender's username etc and receiver because if that's a new discussion, I can't display the avatar/username of sender on receiver's pm list.

Comment: @user3783243  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]

Comment: Unknown column? There should be a message as well. It might be related to the non alias usages, as previously mentioned. You never use `user_receiver`, nor `user_sender`. Also might need to use a left join because will the mapping match both ways?

Comment: Unknown column yep, but I don't know how to use alias. Could you show me please?

Comment: In the future, please include the full error text as part of your question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that because you have aliased the `users` table in both joins, the reference to `users` in the `JOIN` conditions, the `GROUP BY` and `SELECT` list is ambiguous or invalid.

Which username and avatar do you want out of the `SELECT`,the sender or receiver?
Because you've `JOIN`ed twice, with different aliases, you need to be specific *which copy* of the `users` table you are using.

It needs to be either `user_receiver.username` and `user_receiver.avatar` OR `user_sender.username` and `user_sender.avatar`, or all of them.  The reference to `users` is not valid at that point because there is no unaliased `users` table joined in.

Same goes, the aliases of `users` should be used in the `JOIN` conditions

I'm not certain why you are even doing a `GROUP BY`, but the same thing goes there, the `users` reference is not valid because there is no unaliased `users` table in the joins, you have to tell it which copy of the users table to use.

The query should be looking something more like this (I left out the `GROUP BY` because it's unclear what you are trying to accomplish with that without seeing some actual table data.

```
SELECT pm.receiver, pm.date_sent, pm.unread, 
    user_receiver.username AS receiver_name, 
    user_receiver.avatar AS receiver_avatar,
    user_receiver.session_id AS receiver_session_id,
    user_sender.username AS sender_name, 
    user_sender.avatar AS sender_avatar,
    user_sender.session_id AS sender_session_id
FROM pm
INNER JOIN users AS user_receiver ON pm.receiver = user_receiver.id
INNER JOIN users AS user_sender ON pm.sender = user_sender.id
WHERE sender = :id OR receiver = :id 
ORDER BY date_sent ASC
```

Comment: `users.session_id` needs to be duplicated for each alias.

Comment: You should give aliases to all the duplicate column names, e.g. `user_receiver.username AS receiver_username`

Comment: Right on both, I wasn't sure to do with the session_id because I suspected that it may be tangled in with the group by

Answer (score 0):

When you give an alias to a table you can't refer to the original table name any more, you have to use the alias. So `users.columnName` is wrong, you have to use `user_receiver.columnName` or `user_sender.columnName` as appropriate in all those places.

If you always want to select the column from the table corresponding to `:id`, you can use `IF` functions. If you want to select the column for the other user, just change `sender = :id` to `receiver = :id` in those `IF` functions.

There's also no need for `GROUP BY`, you're not aggregating anything.

```
SELECT pm.receiver, pm.date_sent, pm.unread, 
    IF(sender = :id, user_sender.username, user_receiver.username) AS username, 
    IF(sender = :id, user_sender.avatar, user_receiver.avatar) AS avatar,
    IF(sender = :id, user_sender.session_id, user_receiver.session_id) AS session_id
FROM pm
INNER JOIN users AS user_receiver ON pm.receiver = user_receiver.id
INNER JOIN users AS user_sender ON pm.sender = user_sender.id
WHERE sender = :id OR receiver = :id 
ORDER BY date_sent ASC
```

Comment: Hello and thank you! Just missed `FROM pm`, request works now. But it still doesn't give me the list of users who sent a PM. I think we need the `GROUP BY` for this, but how to use it with aliases?

Comment: Why would you need `GROUP BY` for that? That will just combine multiple rows into a single row, it doesn't return additional information.

Comment: My query shows the username and avatar of the user in `:id`. I explained how to get the other user's username and avatar in the second paragraph. You can also just use `user_sender.username` to always get the sender, regardless of whether they're the same as `:id`.

Comment: @Joe278 See the other answer where he returns the names and avatars of both the sender and receiver.

Comment: Because I use datas in a `foreach` loop

Comment: That doesn't explain anything. GROUP BY can't make it return anything more, it makes it return LESS. All the rows with the same value in the grouped column will be combined into a single row. You can use aggregation functions like `SUM()` and `MAX()` to merge the values from some columns in the grouped result.